# Think java chapter 3 exercise 3-4 - Guess My Number

Tags: java, debugging

Hey guys I'm working some exercises from the Think java textbook. I'm working on exercise 3-4 on chapter 4 and I finished writing the code and it works when I run it the first few times but when I try running it again it prints the number generated not the number guessed.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessMyNumber {
    //exercise 3-4
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        //pick a number
        int numberGuessed;
        int numberGenerated;
        int difference;

        //generate a random number
        Random random = new Random();
        numberGenerated = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //prompt for user input
        System.out.println("Im Thinking of a Number between 1 and 100 \nCan you Guess what it is? ");
        System.out.print("Type a Number: ");
        numberGuessed = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your Guess is: " + numberGuessed);
        System.out.println("The Number I was Thinking of is: " + numberGenerated);

        //modulation operator
        difference = numberGenerated % numberGuessed;
        System.out.println(difference);
        System.out.printf("you were of by: %d", difference);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you expect machine to guess the number instead of generating ?

Comment: The behaviour of your program doesn't change, no matter how often you start it. And it is unclear what you mean with " it prints the number generated not the number guessed", you're printing both numbers.

Comment: why are you doing ***difference = numberGenerated % numberGuessed;*** instead of ***difference = numberGenerated - numberGuessed;*** ???

Comment: It's not the "modulation" operator, it's the "modulo" operator, and that is already evident without the comment. The comment should explain _why_ you used the modulo operator and called it a "difference" when it isn't a difference. Also, "I'm" is spelled with an apostrophe, and English doesn't require that a plurality of words be capitalized. Actually, you should review all your prompts for grammar, spelling, and style.

Comment: Question is not clear, please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are confused about is the modulo operation. At least the text does not fit to what it is doing. To calculate what was the difference between the two numbers you would just do

```
difference = numberGenerated - numberGuessed;
```

When you don't want to have negative values you could use

```
difference = java.lang.Math.abs(numberGenerated - numberGuessed);
```

The modulo operator gives you the rest of a division.